# Angular2 How to round number

Tags: angular, pipe

Hi I am trying to round the number I calculated to thousand's place.

For example, If I got 545,000 I want it to be 550,000

I created a pipe

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'round'})
export class RoundPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: number): number {
        return Math.round(value);
    }
}
```

Doesn't seem to work

Any idea?

Comment: Pipe did not work or logic? are you getting an error? post the code where you have applied hte pipe

Comment: no it doesnt give me the number I want maybe coz I didn't set it to calculate to thousand's digit ?

Comment: Yours business logic is unique to your case, don't expect a general function call (`Math.round(value)`) to fit all special cases.

Comment: that's why I'm asking how to fit my unique case :) I

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass another parameter to the pipe giving the number of digits to round to, so it would be called as

```
{{value | round:4}}
```

pick it up in the argument list to `transform`

```
transform(value: number, digits: number): number {
```

and then do the right calculation inside your pipe logic, which would be something like

```
Math.round(value / (10 ** digits)) * (10 ** digits)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is just simple rounding logic. If the value is less than `value%1000` round down, otherwise round up.

```
var toNearest = 10000;
var mod = value % toNearest;
return mod < toNearest/2 ? 
    value - mod :             //round down
    value + (toNearest-mod);  //round up
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Try this =====

import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'round'})
export class RoundPipe {
  transform (input:number) {
    return Math.round(input);
  }
}
```